# JavaFX2 XYChart axis label and custom grid line

Tags: charts, javafx-2

are there methods in javafx2 to override the ticket label X and Y axis so to custom set axis formatter?

2) How to enlarge X or Y axis space in order to get more space for ticket label ?

3) How to set the grid to appear as logarithmic, or redefine dynamically grid line space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enlarge Y axis width you can use

```
yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
```